# Multiple column to different rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display different rows for the data stored in different columns

```
ATTRIBUTE_CHAR1   ATTRIBUTE_CHAR3   ATTRIBUTE_CHAR3 
    ABC1              EFG2             HIJ3 

ROW    ALL ATTRIBUTE
1       ABC1
2       EFG2
3       HIJ3
```

Please suggest a SQL query

Comment: in your column just those 3 values or more

Comment: Hi Uday, welcome to the site. Others will be able to help you better if you provide an example of what you have already tried.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So if there are 20 attributes I have to use 20 union's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use union all

```
select ATTRIBUTE_CHAR1
from table
union all

select ATTRIBUTE_CHAR3
from table
union all

select ATTRIBUTE_CHAR1
from table
```

Comment: So if there are 20 attributes I have to use 20 union's?

Comment: Any function like LISTAGG ?

Comment: @UdayBhaskar no function like this for this purpose avail

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c+, you can use a lateral join:

```
select x.attribute_char
from t cross apply
     (select attribute_char1 as attribute_char from dual union all
      select attribute_char2 as attribute_char from dual union all
      select attribute_char3 as attribute_char from dual
     ) x;
```

You can also use `case` in any version of Oracle:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then attribute_char1
             when n.n = 2 then attribute_char2
             when n.n = 3 then attribute_char3
        end) as attribute_char
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all
      select 2 as n from dual union all
      select 3 as n from dual
     ) n;
```

The advantage to these approaches is that the table is scanned only once.  This can be particularly important if the "table" is really a complex query or view.